# how to open a Excel File after putting data into excel wrokBook and ask user to save automatically.(apache poi java)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i am writing data into excel file using `apache poi` as follows

```
String filename="f:/"+mdy+"MonthlyReport.xls"; 
            HSSFWorkbook hwb=new HSSFWorkbook();  
            HSSFSheet sheet =  hwb.createSheet("MonthlyReport");                                
            HSSFRow rowhead=   sheet.createRow((short)0);      
            rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("MONTH_YEAR ");  
            rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("NO_OF_TICKETS ");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("TOTAL_AMOUNT");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("NO_OF_AGENTS");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("AVERAGE_PRICE");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue("PER_DAY_TICKETS");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue("PER_AGENT_TICKETS");
            PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("select * from MONTHLYREPORTS");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            int i=1;
            while(rs.next()){
            HSSFRow row=   sheet.createRow((short)i);
            row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs.getString(1));
            row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getInt(2));
            row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs.getInt(3));
            row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(rs.getInt(4));
            row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(rs.getInt(5));
            row.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(rs.getInt(6));
            row.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue(rs.getInt(7));
            i++;
            }    


            FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream( filename);
            hwb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
```

i dont want to save the file as

```
FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream( filename);
                hwb.write(fileOut);
```

i want to open the file automatically and ask user to save in their own path.
how to achieve it, please help me .

Comment: ask the user upfront to enter the proper path. you can't open a file which does not exist on your hard drive

Comment: is there any possible to save in context path ask them to download ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean? you can save it anywhere

Comment: when i deploy the project we can't target their hard disk . i want to save it in projects calss path and put some download kind of thing to get file.

Comment: have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076329/java-how-to-user-jfilechooser-to-save-a-excel-file-created-by-apache-poi)

Comment: above example is to choose the file i want wirte work book like above and put it download for user

Comment: is the program running on the users machine or on a server?

Comment: now its under development , should deploy in server.

Comment: then you should inform yourself on how to send files to a client. this question is not suitable for the info you need